# Clojure - Split String without loosing the separator

Tags: string, clojure, split, separator

Does Clojure have a Split function that splits the String into sub-strings including the separator?
Like "a=b", separator "=" 
return: "a", "=", 'b".
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i find regexp to be the simplest variant:

```
user> (re-seq #"[^=]+|=" "asd=dfg=hgf=jjj")
;;=> ("asd" "=" "dfg" "=" "hgf" "=" "jjj")

user> (re-seq #"[^=]+|=" "asd=dfg=hgf=")
;;=> ("asd" "=" "dfg" "=" "hgf" "=")

user> (re-seq #"[^=]+|=" "=dfg=hgf=dffff")
;;=> ("=" "dfg" "=" "hgf" "=" "dffff")
```

Answer (score 1):

`split-with` mostly does this, although it will require a little work on your part.

```
(split-with #(not= \= %) "a=b")
```

Yields

```
[(\a) (\= \b)]
```

The most idiomatic thing I could think of to remedy this was:

```
(->> "a=b=c=d" ; Thread the string through the last argument of...
     (split-with #(not= \= %)) ; Splitting on =
     (flatten) ; Then flattening
     (map str)) ; And turning the characters into strings

("a" "=" "b" "=" "c" "=" "d")
```

This probably won't be performant because of `flatten`, so this won't be practical if this is called constantly on long lists.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, but you can accomplish that using `interpose`:

```
user=> (def mystring "a=b=cde=fg=hij")
#'user/mystring
user=> (interpose "=" (clojure.string/split mystring #"="))
("a" "=" "b" "=" "cde" "=" "fg" "=" "hij")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn split-but-keep 
  "Sep  must be escaped str (er, double escaped actually).
  Use `|` separated seps for multiple e.g. \\(|\\)  as a str for open or close paren"
  [s sep]                                
  (let [re (re-pattern (str "[^" sep "]+|" sep))]
    (re-seq re s)))
```

This is just @leetwinski's answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `clojure.string/split` but put a group round your whole splitting regex.

```
cljs.user=> (def my-regex-with-group #"(=)")
#'cljs.user/my-regex-with-group
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.string :as s])
nil
cljs.user=> (s/split "ab=dd=cb" my-regex-with-group)
["ab" "=" "dd" "=" "cb"]
```

As you can see, this works in Clojurescript too. The regex can be any valid regex.

```
cljs.user=> (s/split "ab=dd=cb" #"(dd=)")
["ab=" "dd=" "cb"]
```

Without the group, the match is omitted

```
cljs.user=> (s/split "ab=dd=cb" #"dd=")
["ab=" "cb"]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- I tried `(s/split "1234a5" #"([^\d])")` in the REPL, with the intention of splitting on and keeping the `a`, but it returns `["1234" "5"]`